# Tengo una tarea de crear un programa que lea de entrada dos cadenas y imprima la más larga o si son iguales

Tags: c

Este es mi código, el programa debe de leer 2 cadenas y decir cuál es más larga o decir si son iguales, pero solo me guarda la 2da cadena y a la hora de mostrarme en pantalla me la muestra incluso incompleta.

````
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char str1 [] = "";
    char str2 [] = "";
    
    gets(str1);
    gets(str2);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    int long_str1 = strlen(str1);
    int long_str2 = strlen(str2);
    
    cout<<"\n\n";
    if(strcmp(str1 , str2) == 0){
        cout<<"Son iguales"<<endl;
    }else if(long_str1 > long_str2){
        cout<<"La cadena "<<str1<<" es mas larga que "<<str2<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"La cadena "<<str2<<" es mas larga que "<<str1<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

El error en tu código proviene de que en la primera comparación usas la función strcmp(). Esta función lo que hace es comparar carácter a carácter si las cadenas son literalmente iguales, sin embargo esto no es lo que quieres que haga el código, independientemente del contenido quieres saber si las cadenas tienen el mismo tamaño. Siguiendo la misma filosofía que en los otros condicionales posteriores, sustituye `strcmp(str1 , str2) == 0` por `long_str1 == long_str2`

---

Fuera de la pregunta te recomiendo no usar la función "gets()" debido a que el buffer interno de esta función no sabe que tamaño va a tener la cadena que va a leer y si se desborda puede ocasionar fallos y aunque algunas versiones de c todavía la admiten, se eliminó oficialmente a partir del estándar del 2011. En su lugar puedes usar la fgets que solventa este problema o la función getline() de POSIX. Espero que te sirva